# Return a static page and set status code

Tags: nginx

My disk has `/var/www/mywebsite/hello.html`

Whenever a visitor visits http://mywebsite.com/hello.html, instead of 200 I want the status code to be 123.

```
server {
    ...

    location /hello.html {
        return 123;
    }
```

I'm using this config file. When I go to http://mywebsite.com/hello.html, I see a blank page but the status code is 123.

How do I see the page content as well as the 123 status code?

**EDIT:**

Can I return hello.html with "402 Payment Required" or "500 Internal Server Error"?

I just need the syntax.

Comment: Are you looking for `curl --head`?  ie `curl --head http://mywebsite.com/hello.html` should show something like `HTTP/2 123`

Answer (score 2):

HTTP won't let you do that: 1xx-series codes cannot contain a response as per [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (i.e., the HTTP protocol):

> 10.1 Informational 1xx

> This class of status code indicates a provisional response, consisting **only** of the Status-Line and optional headers, and is terminated by an empty line.

So even if you could bring your nginx to do that (it's possible, I guess), your browser would likely just not show what it is sent.
(Not showing data sent through responses that should contain no data is actually a good way to make it harder to exploit server bugs that allow an attacker to make a browser make an invalid request, in whose error handling they can inject their own data; so, easy security for the browser user without breaking any webserver that's not *horribly* misconfigured.)

Comment: Looks like it's status code-specific. How about that I want to return "402 Payment Required", with hello.html working like a 404 page?

Comment: yes, that works.

Comment: Is my syntax correct? It doesn't work for me.